# how to use xpath to click the element if the value is greather than?

Tags: javascript, php, xpath, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0

I have XPath, which click the element when the value matches to 1800, but I want this to work only like if the value is greater than 1800, I am noob and I don't know about that I just googled,
Here is working XPath that click on the value 1800, can anyone modify for me,

```
//uni-view/uni-text/span[contains(text(),"1800")]
```

Comment: Could you also supply a source example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking to only select a `span` that contains text `>1800`

Here would be a corresponding sample XML structure,

```
<uni-view>
  <uni-text>
    <span>
      1750
    </span>
    <span>
      1800
    </span>
    <span>
      1850
    </span>
  </uni-text>
</uni-view>
```

You are currently using the XPath contains function which will select all `span` where `span/text()` contains the given string `1800`.
For the given example XML above you will only select the second `span` because `1800` is contained in the `span/text()`.
If you are looking to select all `span` where `span/text()` is '>1800' you can simply remove the XPath contains function and replace it by checking if `span/text() > '1800'`

```
//uni-view/uni-text/span[text() > "1800"]
```

For the given example XML, this will only pull in the third `span` where `span/text()` is `1850`.